# Problem with ::before element and opacity only in Safari

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I'm currently trying to make a Loader for my React application, this loader has a grainy background made with a pseudo-element `::before` which has a background noise image with opacity to make the noise effect. Inside this container, I have 2 logos and a big circle which is a simple svg. At the end of my loading, I simply scale up my circle to fill the entire window and then render my page component.

Here's the thing : in Safari, my big circle appears to be a square! and to be slightly transparent!

Here's the JSX/CSS of my loader:

```html
<div className="z-40 flex items-center justify-center bg-darker-gray grain">
    <img ref={logoRef} src={Logo} className="z-50 w-28 absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 opacity-0"/>
    <img ref={letterLogoRef} src={LetterLogo} className="z-50 h-28 opacity-0 absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"/>
    <img className="h-px w-px z-[1000] absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" ref={bigRoundRef} src={CircleLoader}/>
</div>
```

The CSS (grain is my container with noisy background:

```css
.grain {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grain:before {
  content: "";
  top: -10rem;
  left: -10rem;
  width: calc(100% + 20rem);
  height: calc(100% + 20rem);
  z-index: 45;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/256x256_Dissolve_Noise_Texture.png);
  opacity: 0.1;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-animation: noise 1s steps(2) infinite;
  animation: noise 1s steps(2) infinite;
}
```

I tried multiple things, such as 3D transforming my circle to make it go up front or putting an extra `opacity:1;` to it but nothing seemed to change a thing...

Answer (score 0):

Update : I managed to fix it by replacing my circle image with a simple rounded full div and making it grow by changing the width and height with GSAP instead of using a scale animation and now it works well on every browser